# Add CSS styles via Jquery if the value from a getJSON call is a specific value

Tags: jquery, css, getjson

I'm new to jquery and am hoping for a little help.

I have a page that fetches data in `getJSON` format and inserts said data into an element on the page. The page then refreshes every 2 seconds to fetch updated data.

Example of the element that is being updated on the page:

```
<abbr title="mouse hover description" id="User004">..updated by getJSON..</abbr>
```

Here is how I'm fetching and refreshing the content of the `abbr` element (this works):

```
function refreshData()
    {
        $.getJSON('http://domain.com/Data.php',function(User) {
            $.each(User, function(key, val) {
                $('#'+key).text(val);
              });
            });

    }
    window.setInterval("refreshData()", 2000);
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to:
A) Add CSS styles if the key `user004` has the value 2.
B) Add CSS styles if the key `user004` has the value and another key `user007` is 3.

This is what I have today for the first issue, but I know it's incorrect:

```
$.getJSON('http://domain.com/Data.php',function(User) {
            $.each(User, function(key, val) {
                $('#'+key).text(val) {
                    if ($('#user004:contains("2")'))
                    {
                        $("#"+key).css({color: '#9a4d9e', cursor: 'default'});
                    }
                }
              });
            });
```

Comment: What is incorrect specifically?  Try using `#User004` (note capital `U`)

Comment: How can `'#'+key` be equal to user004 and user 007 for the `B` clause? Can you please clean up the conditional statement communications?

Comment: Is it possible to toggle classes instead for adding your styles?

Comment: @ Travis J - Sorry. Added more details. But the getJSON return multiple results.

Comment: @ gmeben - The class name is equal to the getJSON key. That's the only thing to take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what jQuery is doing when you do a $('#user004:contains("2")').  In that case, jQuery will always return an object (that happens to be jQuery itself).  If you want to check if there is a match, you can use

```
if ($('#user004:contains("2")').length > 0)
```

Though to be perfectly honest, I am not quite sure why you would.  You have both key and value, why not just use them directly instead of pulling them from the DOM?  This just seems inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's quite clear that I haven't a good enough understanding on the works in jquery. Thus my question. If you can direct me in a more correct path, please do so. At the moment I just wasn't sure where or how to execute what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback user1545858.

I ended on the below solution that works just fine at the moment:

```
    function refreshData()
    {
        $.getJSON('http://domain.com/Data.php',function(Callcenter) {
            $.each(Callcenter, function(key, val) {
                $('#'+key).text(val);
              });
            });


        // Add custom style if value equals
        if (($("#User004").text() == "0") && (($("#User007").text() < "4"))) {
            $("#User004").css("color","red");
        }
    }

        // Refresh the above every 2 seconds...
        window.setInterval("refreshData()", 2000);
```